# Integral of a sign function proof

Tags: trigonometry, sign, proof, integral

Can anyone please prove this expression below? I saw this in a paper and trying to see where it is coming from.

```
integral(sign(A*w*cos(w*t+phi))*cos(w*t), t, 0, 2*pi/w) = 4/pi*cos(phi)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

The equality doesn't hold as you copied it, but you can compute it anyway. I will give you some tips on how to proceed:

There are two cases: (1) `cos(phi) >= 0` and (2) `cos(phi) < 0`. Let's consider the first one, the second is similar.

Replace `phi` with `phi - 2kpi` so that `-pi < phi - 2kpi <= pi`. Such a `k` exists because `cos(phi) >= 0`. The result of your expression won't change (why?) and therefore we can restrict ourselves to the case `-pi < phi <= pi`.

Now introduce the change of variable `u = wt + phi`. The expression becomes:

sg(Aw)/w*integral(sg(cos(u))cos(u-phi), u, phi, phi+2pi)

So the problem reduces to compute the integral (`sg(Aw)/w` is constant.)

Split the integral in three:

- `I1`: from `phi` to `pi/2`
- `I2`: from `pi/2` to `(3/2)pi` and
- `I3`: from `(3/2)pi` to `phi+2pi`.

In the first interval `sg(cos(u)) = 1`, in the second `= -1`, in the third `=-1`. So,

```
I1 = integral(cos(u-phi),u,phi,pi/2)
I2 = -integral(cos(u-phi),u,pi/2,(3/2)pi)
I3 = integral(cos(u-phi),u,(3/2)pi,phi+2pi)
```

I think you can follow from here.

Comment: Great explanation Leandro, thank you :)) 

I have this issue related to same topic, I bet you can contribute to this question as well: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578294/evolution-of-hysteresis